# Avoid RawKeyboardListener to listen AlertDialog input

Tags: flutter

> StatelessWidget

I have an `RawKeyboardListener` and I want listening only current page. In the same page I call an `AlertDialog` to input some data (`TextField`) but I don't wanna listen to it, is there a way to avoid that?

```
RawKeyboardListener(
 autofocus: true,
 focusNode: FocusNode(),
 onKey: (value) async {
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found a workaround, probably not the best way but it's working

```
onKey: (value) async {
  final isFocusOnMainPage = 
  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.children.isEmpty ?? true;
  if (isFocusOnMainPage) return; 
...
```